# Rate exceed (Service: AWSSimpleSystemsManagement)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

When I deploy serverless framework to AWS cloudformation stack, I got this error message.

```
Rate exceeded (Service: AWSSimpleSystemManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ThrottlingException; Request ID: ....)
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly returns this one to you but seems like you are deploying too fast or querying the AWSSimpleSystemManagement too fast as you are getting throttling exception.
Double check your code for bugs (maybe you are doing an action N times and not once). If you need to interact with AWSSimpleSystemManagement at this rate probably you can increase the number of requests via a ticket to AWS.
If that’s not the case, open them a ticket.